# kafka Can't receive messages from external producer

Tags: apache-kafka

I have docker in a linux machine, there I download kafka version 1.1.0, also I have run a zookeeper container and expose the port 2181, I change the zookeeper.connect of my server.properties to the one that the zookeeper container, I create an image where I include kafka, this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /app
ADD kafka_2.11-1.1.0 /app
ENTRYPOINT bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

After the image is created I run my kafka container and everything is works great, my problem is when I try to send messages from an external producer, the messages never arrive, I search for this error and I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298071/kafka-not-receiving-message-from-external-producer) where I need to configure the advertised.host.name and advertised.port, but after change those properties and try to run my kafka container I get the next error:

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to ip:9092: Cannot assign requested address.
```

Also I try with this property:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip:9092
```

But I get the same error, if I don't make any change in kafka and I try to send a message from my spring boot application I get this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for prueba-0: 30041 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Can someone help me with this?,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot I found this [link](https://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2017/05/25/how-to-install-kafka-cluster-in-the-docker-containers/), I only need to specify the ip address of the host not the ip of docker container, this ip need to be on the advertised.listeners property:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://myip:9092
```

Hope this helps someone else.